# C++ compiler converting list to const list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This might be something really simple but I can't seem to work it out. Within my `Vertex` I have a `std::list<Edge>` but when I try to call methods on it like `push_front` I get an error saying the `list` is `const` and I can't push into it. I think for some reason the compiler is converting the `std::list<Edge>` to a `const std::list<Edge>`. I know my code isn't set up very well but it's just homework so I'm taking a few shortcuts.

Header file:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <set>
#include <list>

class Edge{
public:
    unsigned int to;
    unsigned int weight;
};

class Vertex{
public:
    unsigned int id;
    std::list<Edge> edges;

    bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const{
        return id < other.id;
    }
};

class Graph{

public:
    void add_vertex(unsigned int id);
    void add_edge(unsigned int from, unsigned int to, unsigned int weight);
    std::set<Vertex> get_vertices();
    std::list<Edge> get_edges(unsigned int id);

private: 
    std::set<Vertex> _vertices;
    unsigned int size = 0;


};
```

Lines causing the error:

```
void Graph::add_edge(unsigned int from, unsigned int to, unsigned int weight) 
{
Vertex find_vert;
find_vert.id = from;
set<Vertex>::iterator from_v = _vertices.find(find_vert);
Edge new_edge;
new_edge.to = to;
new_edge.weight = weight;

from_v->edges.push_front(new_edge); // ERROR HERE
}
```

Compiler Error message from running `g++ -c Graph.cpp`:

```
Graph.cpp:23:38: error: passing ‘const std::list<Edge>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void std::list<_Tp,
_Alloc>::push_front(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Edge; _Alloc = std::allocator<Edge>; std::list<_Tp,
_Alloc>::value_type = Edge]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: You are probably executing that line in a function with `const` qualifiers

Comment: What is `from_v` defined as?

Comment: `from_v` is `set<Vertex>::iterator from_v = _vertices.find(find_vert);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of a `std::set` are implicitly `const`, because changing the contents could invalidate their sort order.

That makes `from_v` implicitly `const` here.

```
set<Vertex>::iterator from_v = _vertices.find(find_vert);
```

And your error is telling you that you're trying to modify a `const` object.

```
   from_v->edges.push_front(new_edge);
// ^^^^^^ const  ^^^^^^^^^^ non-const behavior
```

Comment: ahhh that makes much more sense. Thanks!